# Android Activity Workflow

Tags: android, android-activity

If I launch an android activity with flags ClearTop, and use SetContentView to switch views will these activities still suspend in background and follow the typical workflow with onRestart, onPause, etc.?

All these activities are fired off using startActivity btw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any activity follows Activity Lifecycle. If it has clear top flag then the activities above, if any, all get closed (there will be `onStop` and onDestroy) and that clear top activity becomes the top one because of this. For that activity there will be `onStart` and `onResume`